# Replace words from list of words

Tags: r, string, replace, lapply, stringtokenizer

I have this data frame

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, Text = c("there was not clostridium", "clostridium difficile positive", "test was OK but there was clostridium")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)) 
 ID                                  Text
1  1             there was not clostridium
2  2        clostridium difficile positive
3  3 test was OK but there was clostridium
```

And pattern of stop words

```
stop <- paste0(c("was", "but", "there"), collapse = "|")
```

I would like to go through the Text from ID and remove words from stop pattern
It is important to keep order of words. I do not want to use merge functions.

I have tried this

```
  df$Words <- tokenizers::tokenize_words(df$Text, lowercase = TRUE) ##I would like to make a list of single words

for (i in length(df$Words)){
  
  df$clean <- lapply(df$Words, function(y) lapply(1:length(df$Words[i]),
                                                 function(x) stringr::str_replace(unlist(y) == x, stop, "REPLACED")))
  
  
}
```

But this gives me a vector of logical string not a list of words.

```
> df
  ID                                  Text                                       Words                                           clean
1  1             there was not clostridium                there, was, not, clostridium                      FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
2  2        clostridium difficile positive            clostridium, difficile, positive                             FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
3  3 test was OK but there was clostridium test, was, ok, but, there, was, clostridium FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
```

I would like to get this (replace all words from stop pattern and keep word order)

```
> df
  ID                                  Text                                       Words                                           clean
1  1             there was not clostridium                there, was, not, clostridium                      "REPLACED", "REPLACED", not, clostridium
2  2        clostridium difficile positive            clostridium, difficile, positive                             clostridium, difficile, positive
3  3 test was OK but there was clostridium test, was, ok, but, there, was, clostridium test, "REPLACED", OK, "REPLACED", "REPLACED", "REPLACED", clostridium
```

Comment: I find it unclear what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: Yes, it might be helpful if you show an example of your desired output

Comment: I hope my additional code will help

Comment: Problem with your code is with this part: `unlist(y) == x`. Don't make comparision, just use `unlist(y)`. What you did was to make a vector of `TRUE FALSE...` and then check if in this vector is any of stopwords and if yes - replace it. Of course, in vector `FALSE TRUE FALSE...` none of your stopwords exists, so you get just a vector of TRUE/FALSE without any replaced values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tidyverse solution :

First, you need to modify the stop vector so i contains \b before and after the stop word. \b = word boundary and avoid removing the patterns accidentally from within words.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

stop <- paste0(c("\\bwas\\b", "\\bbut\\b", "\\bther\\b"), collapse = "|")
```

Then remove with str_remove_all.
However, this will leave doble whitespaces, which can be removed with str_replace_all and change two whitespaces with one.

```
df %>% mutate(Words = str_remove_all(Text, stop)) %>%
       mutate(Words = str_replace_all(Words, "\\s{2}", " "))
```

This yields the following results (added a "I was bit by a wasp" to check it didn't erase it.

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
     ID Text                                  Words                         
  <int> <chr>                                 <chr>                         
1     1 there was not clostridium             there not clostridium         
2     2 clostridium difficile positive        clostridium difficile positive
3     3 test was OK but there was clostridium test OK there clostridium     
4     4 I was bit by a wasp                   I bit by a wasp
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried. But it remove even a chunk of string within a word. EG. word "wasp" turns into "p" because of "was" in stop string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data.table` for it

```
df = as.data.table(df)[, clean := lapply(Words, function(x) gsub(stop, "REPLACED", x))]
```

Or you can use `dplyr` (and don't create column Words):

```
df$clean = lapply(strsplit(df$Text, " "), function(x) gsub(stop, "REPLACED", x))
```

Comment: Thank you I tried. Gsub works just fine, when in text there si no words that contains part of stop string like "wasp" -> "p".

Comment: If `stop = "p|wasp"` it's true, but you can write like this: `stop = "^p$|^wasp$"` and find only whole words.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rflashtext`:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, Text = c("there was not clostridium", "clostridium difficile positive", "test was OK but there was clostridium")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)) 

library(rflashtext)

processor <- KeywordProcessor$new(keys = c("was", "but", "there"),
                                  words = rep.int("REPLACED", 3L))

df$Clean <- strsplit(processor$replace_keys(df$Text), split = " ", fixed = TRUE)

df

  ID                                  Text
1  1             there was not clostridium
2  2        clostridium difficile positive
3  3 test was OK but there was clostridium
                                                          Clean
1                          REPLACED, REPLACED, not, clostridium
2                              clostridium, difficile, positive
3 test, REPLACED, OK, REPLACED, REPLACED, REPLACED, clostridium
```